# AttributeError: 'KeywordAnalyzer' object has no attribute 'tk'. Did you mean: 'tr'?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
import os
import re
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout


class KeywordAnalyzer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # 设置窗口的大小和位置
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)

        # 创建文本编辑框
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.setReadOnly(True)

        # 创建按钮
        self.choose_folder_button = tk.Button(self, text="选择文件夹", command=self.choose_folder)
        self.analyze_button = tk.Button(self, text="分析文件", command=self.analyze_files)

        # 设置布局
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.choose_folder_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.analyze_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Here is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55zyI.png)
I'm fairly new to tkinter, and this error has me stumped. I'd really appreciate any help, thank you!

I'm fairly new to tkinter, and this error has me stumped. I'd really appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Please post all code and errors as plain text.

Comment: `QWidget` is not compatible with `tkinter`. You should not be importing and using things from `PyQt5` and `tkinter` together under normal circumstances.

Comment: Tkinter and QT are different UI libraries and I doubt they are compatible. You are defining self.choose_folder_button as as tkinter button and then trying to add that to layout, a QVBoxLayout. Try using QPushbuttons instead

Comment: Here is my error respnse:
AttributeError: 'KeywordAnalyzer' object has no attribute 'tk'. Did you mean: 'tr'?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
self.choose_folder_button = tk.Button(self, text="选择文件夹", command=self.choose_folder)
```

You are trying to pass the instance of `KeywordAnalyzer` (`self`) as the master when creating an instance of `tk.Button`. You cannot do that. The master of a tkinter widget must be another tkinter widget. You cannot use a PyQt5 widget as a parent of a tkinter widget, they are completely incompatible.